# Infopath submit filename multiple fields

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, file

Using the Submit Options on Infopath 2013, I am trying to figure out how to generate a filename based on two of my form fields.

Name
Device Model

For example I would like the filename to be: "Steve Jobs - iPhone 7"

Currently I've only managed to generate filename as only the Name.

Any pointers would be great! :)

Comment: Are you using a button the submit using a action rule?

Answer (score 0):

After much research and testing I've managed to self-resolve this by using the below concat statement:

```
concat(Name, " - ", DeviceModel)
```